# Elegant way for selecting "best" row for each category in grouped query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to select the "best" row (i.e. one with a maximum/minimum score) for each item type from a table.

For a simple example, let's say I have run a large poll on how popular different colors are for different types of fruit, and determined the following scores for some fruit-color combinations:

```
  Fruit    | Color   | Score              
  ==========================
  apples   | red     | 5
  apples   | yellow  | 5
  apples   | green   | 4
  apples   | blue    | 0
  bananas  | brown   | 1
  bananas  | blue    | 0
  bananas  | yellow  | 5
  kiwis    | orange  | 1
  kiwis    | brown   | 5
  kiwis    | blue    | 0
```

Now I want to tell my product design team what color they should choose for each fruit. If two colors are equally popular, I want the one that comes first alphabetically, just to have a deterministic result.

Probably the normal way of doing this would be to write a program that queries the database for a list of all fruits (pseudocode), then runs a foreach like this:

```
  result = query("SELECT DISTINCT fruit FROM fruits;")
  foreach fruit in result:
      color = query("SELECT color FROM fruits WHERE fruit='$fruit' ORDER BY score DESC, color LIMIT 1")
      print "The $fruit should be $color."
```

If I want to do it in SQL, I can calculate the scores in a subquery, then selecting the rows that match the score or join on them (using MIN and GROUP BY to get rid of possible duplicates):

```
SELECT fruit, MIN(color) FROM
  fruits
  JOIN 
    (SELECT fruit, max(score) AS score FROM fruits GROUP BY fruit)
  USING (fruit, score)
GROUP BY fruit
```

You can find the example data and this query in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/44815/1).

**Is there a more elegant way of solving this only in SQL/SQLite?**

The join-on-itself may not look too bad in this simple example because I can get rid of the duplicates here with the MAX + GROUP BY trick. If I had additional columns that I need to select, e.g. the number of people willing to buy the fruit in that color, I would have to nest the query *again*. This results in monstronsities like this:

```
SELECT fruit, color, interested FROM
  (
    SELECT fruit, color, interested FROM
      fruits
      JOIN 
        (SELECT fruit, max(score) AS score FROM fruits GROUP BY fruit)
      USING (fruit, score)
  ) 
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT fruit, min(color) as color FROM
      fruits
      JOIN 
        (SELECT fruit, max(score) AS score FROM fruits GROUP BY fruit)
      USING (fruit, score)
    GROUP BY fruit
  )
  USING (fruit, color)
```

([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e5d23/2) for the monstrosity)

Comment: Windowing functions in PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc make a query like this very simple. (I didn't post this as an answer since I realize that SQLite != PostgreSQL. But if you have this sort of requirement commonly, then it could be worth considering other DBMSs to make things easy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining both sort columns into a single value allows you to use a simple MIN.
This requires [formatting](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf) the score values as a fixed-length string:

```
SELECT fruit,
       MIN(printf("%10d", score) || color)
FROM fruits
GROUP BY fruit
```

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, non-aggregated columns are guaranteed to come from the same record that matches a MIN/MAX ([changelog](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html)):

```
SELECT fruit,
       score,
       color,
       interested,
       MIN(printf("%10d", score) || color)
FROM fruits
GROUP BY fruit
```

Comment: The formatting approach is as disgusting as it is brilliant. I like it! The real winner is the second part though, thank you for that - that is exactly what I was looking for. I added a link to the changelog; I wonder why this is not documented in a better way, since this is really really useful.

Comment: For people who find this later: After a short chat in #sqlite on freenode, it seems that this behavior is intentionally undocumented and may fail on more complex queries. If you use it, be careful and verify the results.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: the best I can think of now to respect the alphabetic order is:

```
SELECT fruit, min(color) AS color 
FROM (
    SELECT fruit, color, score, interested
    FROM fruits AS f1 
    GROUP BY fruit, score, color
    HAVING score = (
        SELECT MAX(score)
        FROM fruits AS f2
        WHERE f2.fruit = f1.fruit
    )
)
GROUP BY fruit
```

This answers your first question, returning the correct pairs of `fruit`, `color` you asked for.

If you want to select other columns you can use the result of this query to work out the rows you're interested in (e.g. once you know that *"apples should be blue"* you can query the table again using these values).

Actually

```
SELECT fruit, min(color), score, interested FROM (
```

also works, but it is be bad practice and it's not even supported by some databases.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The alphabetic order is not specified, so if it does output red, it is random/caused by the order of the input. Indeed, if I change the input order, I get yellow for the apples with your query.

Comment: @JanSchejbal: you were right! I updated my answer. Still not perfect, but pretty close :)